# For FreeIPA autodiscovery to work, what SRV records must exist on the DNS server?

Tags: domain-name-system, freeipa, autodiscovery

I've configured FreeIPA for the most part. When I attempt to add a client, I must manually specify the domain and IPA server FQDN. I've read many sources discussing autodiscovery, but I have yet to find an example of the autodiscovery records.

My IPA servers are the authoritative DNS resolver for their domain.

Comment: 1000 views, and still no upvotes. Boo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your authoritative DNS server is not FreeIPA, you can run the following command on your IPA server to generate the necessary DNS records, which you can then go and put into your authoritative DNS zone file:

```
ipa dns-update-system-records --dry-run
```

See https://www.freeipa.org/page/Howto/Updating_FreeIPA_system_DNS_records_on_a_remote_DNS_server for more information.

If FreeIPA is your authoritative DNS server, you can regenerate your DNS records on the fly by running the same command, with*out* the `---dry-run` flag. If you're not sure your records are correct, or want to see the records, use the `--dry-run` flag to compare and contrast what is currently configured in the system.

Comment: The IPA servers are the authoritative DNS resolvers.

Comment: Before you enroll a new client, what DNS servers are those clients configured to use?

Comment: The clients are configured to use IPA1 and IPA2 as their resolvers. Using DiG, I've verified IPA1 is the responder used.

Comment: Try running the dns-update-systems-records --dry-run command that I provided, and compare stdout with what you see in the FreeIPA gui. If there's a difference, then take out the --dry-run flag to actually update the records on your system.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the --dry-run flag. I did exactly what you suggested, and found I had changed the config slightly since before installing IPA. All works well now.

Comment: Awesome! For posterity, I'll go back and edit this answer a little bit to clarify what it does with and without that flag. Glad it helped.